# CustomView - как определить, что компонент находится в интерфейсбилдере?

Tags: swift, xcode

Разрабатываю свой элемент управления.

```
@IBDesignable class ATInputMessageView: UIView {
     bla 
     bla 
     bla 
    }
```

Для построения интерфейса использую XIB файл 
После загрузки из XIB файла я применяю "Тему", которая существует только в процессе работы программы.
Соответственно, когда я пытаюсь отобразить этот элемент управления в ИнтерфейсБилдере - тот выпадает по причине отсутствия этой темы ... в связи с чем появляется вопрос:

В C# при разработке визуальных компонентов используется конструкция

```
if (this.DesignMode) ...
```

Я где то встречал на просторах интернета подобную конструкцию для SWIFT/XCode

Может кто-то знает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью макроса `TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER`

```
#if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
    // рендер из IB
#else
    // обычный запуск
#endif
```

Также есть метод `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()`, который выполняется только при запуске из IB